# Sum of the nested list rows apart from from first value of each list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have to find the mean and median of the nested list rows with strings as their first values I tried the code below to firstly find out their sum

```
x = [['aus', 1, 2, 7, 4, 5], ['argentina', 1, 1, 3, 4, 5], ['nigeria',   1, 2, 6, 4, 4]]
for i in x:
    y=list(map(sum, i[1:]))
    print(y)
```

but it says

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

the result needs to be

```
[['aus',26], ['argentina', 14], ['nigeria', 17]]
```

Comment: You are trying to apply `sum` to individual numbers, and then make a `list` from that single `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> [[i, sum(j)] for i, *j in x]
[['aus', 19], ['argentina', 14], ['nigeria', 17]]
```

If you want to stick with an explicit for-loop closer to your current form, you don't need `map()` here.  Just take the sum of everything but the 0th element:

```
>>> s = []
>>> for i in x:
...     s.append([i[0], sum(i[1:])])
... 
>>> s
[['aus', 19], ['argentina', 14], ['nigeria', 17]]
```

Using unpacking:

```
>>> for i, *j in x:
...     s.append([i, sum(j)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the more elegant answer from [@BradSolomon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7954504/brad-solomon), but if iterable unpacking seems confusing then you can be a bit more explicit and slice the part of the list that you want to sum. Also, you can use the `statistics` module for mean and median.

```
from statistics import mean, median

nums = [['aus', 1, 2, 7, 4, 5], ['argentina', 1, 1, 3, 4, 5], ['nigeria', 1, 2, 6, 4, 4]]

sums = [[n[0], sum(n[1:])] for n in nums]
print(sums)
# [['aus', 19], ['argentina', 14], ['nigeria', 17]]

means = [[n[0], mean(n[1:])] for n in nums]
print(means)
# [['aus', 3.8], ['argentina', 2.8], ['nigeria', 3.4]]

medians = [[n[0], median(n[1:])] for n in nums]
print(medians)
# [['aus', 4], ['argentina', 3], ['nigeria', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, just a little change:

```
for i in x:
    y = sum(i[1:])
    print(i[0], y)
```